# EditorGridPanel : Error Ext.reg is not a function

Tags: extjs, combobox

I tried ti add a combobox in my Grid using EditorGridPanel but I get an error that i can't resolve .

The error :
 ***Ext.reg is not a function
   Ext.reg('editorgridpanel', Ext.ux.grid.EditorGridPanel);***

In my file EditorGridPAnel.js i do :

> Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.EditorGridPanel' ,{
>        extend : 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
>        alias  : 'EditorGridPanel.editorgrid',
>      -- 
>      -- 
>      --
>     Ext.reg('editorgridpanel', Ext.ux.grid.EditorGridPanel);

If someone can help me please .. since Friday I try to resolve it but nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on a MVC application and want to create an extension of a grid and then want to use an instance of that grid with the xtype. you have have to set the alias as widget.xtypename.

`Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.userlist'
});`

Comment: I have juste a word : Thank You very much

Comment: Hi I have a question .. I've done your solution but I have a problem ;